# document.getElementById no me captura el valor de un input

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="/authenticate" method="POST" id="nickForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="title pb-1" for="username">User</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nickname" placeholder="Enter user" name="username">
            <div class="form-text">The key to success is to sleep well.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="title pt-2 pb-1" for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Check1">
            <label class="title form-check-label" for="Check1">Remember username</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="nickForm" value="login">LOGIN</button>
    </form>
```

Y tengo el siguiente script:

```
<script>
    const socket = io();
    var form = document.getElementById('nickForm');
    var user = document.getElementById('nickname');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        if (user) {
            socket.emit('name', user);
        }
    })
</script>
```

Al ejecutarlo este no me muestra el contenido del input:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si le coloco un valor directo a la variable user este si lo muestra:

```
<script>
    const socket = io();
    var form = document.getElementById('nickForm');
    var user = "Hola";
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        if (user) {
            socket.emit('name', user);
        }
    })
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en esto, podrían explicarme que estoy haciendo mal, de antemano muchas gracias por la atención brindada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta el .value en la variable user para tomar el valor del input.

```
 <script>
  const socket = io();
  var form = document.getElementById('nickForm');
  var user = document.getElementById('nickname');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    if (user) {
        socket.emit('name', user.value);
    }
  })
  </script>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, si funcionó.